# Second Idea window not shown in taskbar

Tags: kde, taskbar, intellij

I open a different project in IntelliJ IDEA in a new window, this window appears but never shown in task bar. So I can't access this window once it loses focus, other than by minimizing other windows until it shows up. Is there a way to make it appear there?

Doesn't happen every time but does happen around every other time.

I'm using KDE desktop. In `xprop` there's nothing immediately suspicious, only that the problematic window lacks `_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY`. It looks like plasma decided to ignore my window for good. Nothing special configured for those windows either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is an open bug on intellij idea, quite a long pending one. I too am facing this issue. Currently marked at Normal priority, under Cosmetics category, I dont think there are enough KDE users out there to warrant enough attention to fix it.

Here is a link to the bug report, please upvote and show that you too are in need of a fix for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149703